# Error with credentials file in IVONA SpeechCloud Java SDK

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, text-to-speech

I am simply trying to implement the [IVONA SpeechCloud Java SDK](https://github.com/IvonaSoftware/ivona-speechcloud-sdk-java/) (with the specific sample file **SampleIvonaSpeechCloudCreateSpeech.java**, which should be able to run "as is") in the IntelliJ IDEA IDE, but keep getting an error about the AWS credentials file which can not be loaded.

This is how it looks like:
[image: Screenshot from IntelliJ IDEA]

After downloading the IVONA SpeechCloud Java SDK and creating a new project from existing source with Maven dependency, I updated the **IvonaCredentials.properties** file with my personal `accessKey` and `secretKey`

I also updated the `<dependencies>` field in the **pom.xml** file with the following code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ivona</groupId>
    <artifactId>ivona-speechcloud-sdk-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Does someone know how to fix the `Unable to load AWS credentials from the /resources/IvonaCredentials.properties file on the classpath` error?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured this out after a few hours of messing around in the source files. You can make your own Provider Class where you can pass the credentials in as String Parameters.

**This is my custom credential Class "IvonaCredentials"**

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;

public class IvonaCredentials implements AWSCredentialsProvider{

public IvonaCredentials(String mSecretKey, String mAccessKey) {
    super();
    this.mSecretKey = mSecretKey;
    this.mAccessKey = mAccessKey;
}

private String mSecretKey;
private String mAccessKey;

@Override
public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new AWSCredentials() {

        @Override
        public String getAWSSecretKey() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mSecretKey;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mAccessKey;
        };
    };
    return awsCredentials;
}

@Override
public void refresh() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

**This is how I call my class**

```
private static void init() {
    speechCloud = new IvonaSpeechCloudClient(new IvonaCredentials("secretKey", "accessKey"));
    speechCloud.setEndpoint("https://tts.eu-west-1.ivonacloud.com");
}
```